# How to post SAML Response message using NSURLConnection?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsurlconnection, saml

I am creating an iPhone app that allows users to interact with a secured server. However, to authenticate the user the app needs to go through SAML from the server the user logs into to the server the data is on (providing SSO). So the app is mimicking sending SAML HTTP requests (where normally the browser would take care of).

The process is working with Ruby using the Mechanize gem, but now I cannot get it to work on the iPhone with NSURLConnection.

The problem I run into is: it seems the base64 encoded SAML Response is not sent properly by NSURLConnection to the server. The + signs are replaced by spaces, causing the decoding of the SAML Response on the server side to fail. Using URL encoding with stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding results in the same decoding error.

This is the code extracting and sending the SAML Response:

```
// Extract the SAML Response from the form that is sent by the server
body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[self receivedData]     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *searchSAMLResponseStart = @"name=\"SAMLResponse\" value=\"";
NSString *searchSAMLResponseEnd = @">\n<NOSCRIPT><INPUT TYPE=\"SUBMIT\"";
NSRange samlResponseStartRange = [body rangeOfString:searchSAMLResponseStart options:0];
NSRange samlResponseEndRange = [body rangeOfString:searchSAMLResponseEnd options:0];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange (NSMaxRange(samlResponseStartRange), samlResponseEndRange.location - NSMaxRange(samlResponseStartRange) -1);
NSString* samlResponseString = [body substringWithRange:range];

// Construct the SAML POST request
NSURL               *url;
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
url = [NSURL URLWithString:kSamlPostUrl];
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *userAgent = kUserAgent;
[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *post = [@"RelayState=https://example.com&SAMLResponse=" stringByAppendingString:samlResponseString];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

// Send the request        
self.connectionPostSaml = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

The SAML form that the server sends and where the SAML Response is taken from, looks like this:

```
<html>
<HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV='PRAGMA' CONTENT='NO-CACHE'><META HTTP-EQUIV='CACHE-CONTROL'     CONTENT='NO-CACHE'><TITLE>SAML 2.0 Auto-POST form</TITLE></HEAD>
   <body onLoad="document.forms[0].submit()">
<NOSCRIPT>Your browser does not support JavaScript.  Please click the 'Continue' button     below to proceed. <br><br></NOSCRIPT>
      <form action="https://sso.example.com/saml2" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="https://example.com">
         <input type="hidden" name="SAMLResponse"     value="PFJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6cHJvdG9jb2wiIERl
c3RpbmF0aW9uPSJodHRwczovL3Nzby5vcG93ZXIuY29tL3NwL0FDUy5zYW1sMiIgSUQ9Il85ZWY0
M2MzMGRkZmQ0YzY1ODNiMjgxZjAwNDU5ZWQyMjZmMjQiIElzc3VlSW5zdGFudD0iMjAxMi0wMy0y
OFQyMTo0MDowNloiIFZlcnNpb249IjIuMCI+CiAgICA8bnMxOklzc3VlciB4bWxuczpuczE9InVy
bjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDphc3NlcnRpb24iIEZvcm1hdD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5h
bWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOm5hbWVpZC1mb3JtYXQ6ZW50aXR5Ij5wZ2UuY29tPC9uczE6SXNzdWVy
(…)
cnRpb24+CjwvUmVzcG9uc2U+">
<NOSCRIPT><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Continue"></NOSCRIPT>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

And the error that the server produces after receiving the POST request:

```
Unable to parse incoming SAML2 message, raw:     PFJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6cHJvdG9jb2wiIERl
c3RpbmF0aW9uPSJodHRwczovL3Nzby5vcG93ZXIuY29tL3NwL0FDUy5zYW1sMiIgSUQ9Il9iN2Q5
OTZhMmI1MjhiNWRkNjY0YWM4YjUwZmVjM2M2OTMzMWEiIElzc3VlSW5zdGFudD0iMjAxMi0wMy0y
OVQyMjowMzoxNVoiIFZlcnNpb249IjIuMCI CiAgICA8bnMxOklzc3VlciB4bWxuczpuczE9InVy
bjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDphc3NlcnRpb24iIEZvcm1hdD0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5h
bWVzOnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOm5hbWVpZC1mb3JtYXQ6ZW50aXR5Ij5wZ2UuY29tPC9uczE6SXNzdWVy
PgogICAgPFN0YXR1cz4KICAgICAgICA8U3RhdHVzQ29kZSBWYWx1ZT0idXJuOm9hc2lzOm5hbWVz
OnRjOlNBTUw6Mi4wOnN0YXR1czpTdWNjZXNzIi8 CiAgICA8L1N0YXR1cz4KICAgIDxuczI6QXNz
(…)
```

Notice how the + signs in the raw response are changed into spaces.

It seems normal behavior for the server to decode the received response and hence replacing + signs with spaces, however: why does it work when the SAML form is posted from the browser, but not from NSURLConnection?

To solve I tried:

- using different encodings to decode and encode the SAML Response. Now using NSUTF8StringEncoding, also tried: NSASCIIStringEncoding, NSNEXTSTEPStringEncoding, NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding, NSUnicodeStringEncoding
- using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding, so this line of code:

  NSString* samlResponseString = [body substringWithRange:range];

becomes:

```
NSString* samlResponseString = [[body substringWithRange:range] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

- using other enctypes for the form, but the server won't even accept those requests:
  multipart/form-data
  text/plain

I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem sending base64 via post and solved it by url encoding. Try this:

```
NSString *post = [@"RelayState=https://example.com&SAMLResponse=" stringByAppendingString:
        (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
        (__bridge CFStringRef)samlResponseString, NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
        CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))];
```